# Get Distinct rows according to one column and order by date

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have the following scenario which can solved on the database level or the Linq to EF level:
Here is my view in the database:

```
id  title   date           weight
==================================
1   t1     2013-01-18       1.5
1   t1     2013-01-17       1.4
1   t1     2013-01-15       1.31
1   t1     2013-01-12       1.22
2   t2     2013-01-19       2.3
2   t2     2013-01-16       2.1
2   t2     2013-01-07       1.81
2   t2     2013-01-19       1.62
```

What I need as a result is one record from each item (t1 and t2) which is the newest one by date.

So the output will be like this:

```
id  title   date           weight
==================================
1   t1     2013-01-18       1.5
2   t2     2013-01-19       2.3
```

As I said above Answers on the database level or the linq level using (Distinct) are both welcomed.

Part of my c# linq:

```
mylist = (from a in db.myview
join art in db.viewTags on a.id equals art.ArticleID
where (art.TagID == tag.ID)
select a).Distinct().Take(10).ToList();
```

I need distinct records from myview according to a.id (id field of the view)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT** - as per update you want distinct by id

Full article : [**DistinctBy in Linq (Find Distinct object by Property)**](http://pranayamr.blogspot.in/2013/01/distinctby-in-linq.html)

Following is part of [MoreLINQ](http://morelinq.googlecode.com) library.

Use `DistinctBy` function

```
public static IEnumerable<TSource> DistinctBy<TSource, TKey>
    (this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
{
    HashSet<TKey> seenKeys = new HashSet<TKey>();
    foreach (TSource element in source)
    {
        if (seenKeys.Add(keySelector(element)))
        {
            yield return element;
        }
    }
}
```

So to find the distinct values using just the `Id` property, you could use:

```
mylist = (from a in db.myview
 join art in db.viewTags on a.id equals art.ArticleID
 where (art.TagID == tag.ID)
 select a).DistinctBy(a=>a.Id).Take(10).ToList();
```

---

```
select * from table 
inner join
(select max(date) as date,id from table group by id) d 
on d.id = table.id and d.date= table.date
```

Comment: I already have a join in my linq select statement, so can i do this join? and one more thing I need to return all the fields from the view which are around 10 rows

Comment: @AliIssa - if you can paste some code tha i can help you on that...because i cannot directly say something on this..

Comment: the first and second parts of code are related? also I can't do this "Distinct(a=>a.Id)" I am getting an error: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<myview>' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: @AliIssa - hey you need to use DistinctBy method and need ot include morelinq.dll in your project ...that will do work for you..

Comment: also I don't have distinctby, I am using entity framework 4.1

Comment: from where can i download morelinq.dll?

Comment: @AliIssa - here is link from where you can download it : https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/downloads/list

Answer (score 1):

the following will give you one single line even if there are 2 weight for the same date:

```
declare @t table (
    id int,
    title varchar(50),
    date datetime,
    weight decimal(19,4)
)

insert into @t (id, title, date, weight) values
   (1, 't1', '20130118', 1.5),
   (1, 't1', '20130118', 1.6),
   (2, 't2', '20130116', 1.4),
   (2, 't2', '20130115', 1.2)

select
    *
from
    (
        select ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by id order by date desc) rn, * 
        from @t
    ) v
where rn = 1
```