# Select distinct group of records according to one column then order them by datetime

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select

I want to select distinct groups of records according to one column value then order them by datetime.

For example, I have this table of data

```
+----+---------+-------+---------------------------+
| id | Name    | Index | DateTime                  |
+----+---------+-------+---------------------------+
|  3 | Index   | 1     | 2016-03-03 12:03:15.353   |
|  4 | Index   | 1     | 2016-03-01 12:03:15.353   |
|  5 | Middle  | 2     | 2016-03-03 12:03:15.353   |
|  6 | Little  | 3     | 2016-03-03 12:03:15.353   |
|  7 | Thumb   | 4     | 2016-03-03 12:03:15.353   |
|  8 | Thumb   | 4     | 2016-03-01 12:03:15.353   |
+----+---------+-----------------------------------+
```

I want to get result like this:

```
+----+---------+-------+---------------------------+
| id | Name    | Index | DateTime                  |
+----+---------+-------+---------------------------+
|  3 | Index   | 1     | 2016-03-03 12:03:15.353   |
|  5 | Middle  | 2     | 2016-03-03 12:03:15.353   |
|  6 | Little  | 3     | 2016-03-03 12:03:15.353   |
|  7 | Thumb   | 4     | 2016-03-03 12:03:15.353   |
+----+---------+-----------------------------------+

+----+---------+-------+---------------------------+
| id | Name    | Index | DateTime                  |
+----+---------+-------+---------------------------+    
|  4 | Index   | 1     | 2016-03-01 12:03:15.353   |    
|  8 | Thumb   | 4     | 2016-03-01 12:03:15.353   |
+----+---------+-----------------------------------+
```

Consider a fingerprint system that save all fingerprints and not override if the same finger re-enrolled, I want to retrieve the latest fingers enrolled and the history for them if a finger re-enrolled more than one time.

I tried this query which return the distinct records according to index:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM    Fingerprint a
INNER JOIN 
      (SELECT DISTINCT [Index], MIN(Id) as id
       FROM Fingerprint 
       GROUP BY [Index]) AS b
ON a.[Index] = b.[Index] 
    AND a.id = b.id

WHERE [RefNumber] = '00000'

ORDER BY [LastUpdatedOn] DESC
```

How I can achieve this be sql query?

---

I found a similar question here:
[Get Distinct rows according to one column and order by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14464176/get-distinct-rows-according-to-one-column-and-order-by-date)

Using LINQ to retrieve the distinct records without the history.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logic:**

Use `Partition` function to calculate a rank based on `id` column and then order by rank, followed by order on id column

```
select [id], [Name], [Index], [DateTime] from
(
 Select 
     *, 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by Name order by id asc) as rr
 from Fingerprint
 ) t
order by rr asc, id asc
```

**screenshot of output:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks @DhruvJoshi, it works, can I filter the result to choose to which level I can retrieve, for example I want to retrieve only the latest set of fingers or return two sets, etc.

Comment: Yes you can. You can add a where clause like  `WHERE rr =2` before the `ORDER BY' statement to retrieve the desired rows.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would probably be with the windowing [`row_number()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function:

```
SELECT [id], [Name], [Index], [DateTime]
FROM   (SELECT [id], [Name], [Index], [DateTime],
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [DateTime] AS rn
        FROM   Fingerprint) f
WHERE   rn = 1
```